# How to use read.csv or read.table to read comma delimited file where fields have comma and double quotes

Tags: r

Wondering if someone knows how to use `read.table` or `read.csv` to read a comma delimited file where the fields also have command and/or double quotes?

example:

```
time, pid, commandline
----------------------
1:00, 123, ksh "test.ksh";echo "hello, world"
```

as you can see column commandline have both double quotes and comma. I have used both read.table and read.csv and added extra double quotes around commandline field, hello and world is split. Any ideas how to import such field?

Comment: Time to find the person who created the archive with a comma as a delimiter and whack him over the head? :-(  .   I noticed that MSoft Excel cannot import this properly either.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this happen a few times. I use the `stringr` package to workaround it entirely.

```
library(stringr)    
x <- '1:00, 123, ksh "test.ksh";echo "hello, world"' 
# You'll probably just use readLines(file("mydata.txt"))
str_split_fixed(x,", ",3)

     [,1]   [,2]  [,3]                                    
[1,] "1:00" "123" "ksh \"test.ksh\";echo \"hello, world\""
```

Comment: if you absolutely need the text without escapes you can use ?cat