# Read text file with separator longer than one character with fread

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to get data.table `fread` to read text file with separators like `"|||"`?

I have a text file (2GB) that has lines that look like

```
aaa|||bbb|||random characters !$^!$£"!$ contain single |. |||other cols
```

If it's not possible to use `fread`, any other recommendation? I'll get them into `data.table` in the end.

Comment: first `fread()` and then splitting the string with `strsplit()`

Comment: or read.table(sep="|||") and then setDT?

Comment: @Heroka, I tried read.table but that gives a similar error `invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte`

Comment: Maybe this post helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186357/importing-csv-file-with-multiple-character-separator-to-r

Comment: No native support for this. If on *nix smth like `fread("sed 's/|||/,/g' yourfile")` would be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

The command `read_delim` from the package `readr` supports delimiters with more than one character.

I ran some benchmarks (1.6 mil rows, 30 columns, 350 mb txt file).

I find that it is approx 40% quicker than a solution using `strsplit` in the following manner:

```
do.call(rbind,strsplit(readLines('test.txt'),'~~~',fixed=T))
```

If you install `gawk` for windows and set appropriate system paths in windows, you can also do:

```
fread("sed 's/|||/,/g' yourfile", sep = ',')
```

as suggested by eddi in the comments. This is about 20% slower than the `read_delim` solution as it has to write a temporary file from calling `sed` but faster than the base R solution.

The fastest solution is to use fread with `sep = '|'` and remove the duplicated columns yourself. This works the best if you know apriori where they are, otherwise it can be calculated (presumably at some non-trivial time cost).

I could not get `fread` and `tstrsplit` to complete for my dataset, but you may have better luck.

Comment: it may be possible to improve the sed performance by opening a text connection to the output of sed, so that fread does not have to write (and read) a temporary file.