# read a file with two separator in r

Tags: r, dataset, readfile

I have a problem in reading a file that has this kind of format:

```
1::122::5::838985046
1::185::5::838983525
1::231::5::838983392
1::292::5::838983421
1::316::5::838983392
```

but I cant set two separator and separate columns of data

can anyone halp me read this file in r?

this file can be found in this link:
http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-10m.zip

Comment: Try with `readLines` and then use `separate` from `tidyr`

Comment: when I try to use `readLines` I get this error:

`Error in readLines(file) : 'con' is not a connection`

Comment: `readLine` solution  by Akrun should work; also check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694870/read-text-file-with-separator-longer-than-one-character-with-fread

Comment: I have just tried the function in the first answer of the link provided by @storaged and it worked. So I will vote to close as dupe.

Comment: Yes ... that worked.. thank you