# How to import a one lined flat file .txt with much information in R

Tags: r, flat-file, flatfilereader

my test.txt file looks like this

```
"Nr" | | "X1" | | "ID_T20" | | "Herstellernummer" | | "Werksnummer" | | "Fehlerhaft" "1" | | 1 | | "20-211-2111-14" | | "211" | | "2111" | | 0
```

I tried a lot of commands to import it as a data frame like this:

```
 "Nr" , "X1" , "ID_T20"         , "Hersteller" , "Werksnummer" , "Fehlerhaft"

 "1" ,   1  , "20-211-2111-14" , "211"        , "2111"        ,0
```

can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing "csv" file with multiple-character separator to R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186357/importing-csv-file-with-multiple-character-separator-to-r)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly:

```
x = strsplit(readLines(x), "\\|\\|")[[1]]
x = data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors=F)
```