# "," separator in read.csv - R

Tags: r, csv, import

How to define `","` as the column separator (`sep`) in `read.csv` in R?
I have tried `read.csv(file=x,header = FALSE,sep = "","")`, which doest work correctly.

Comment: The default separator in `read.csv` is already comma.  So, just omit the `sep=","` part and it should work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I have the double quotation as well that I want to use as the seperator.

Comment: You may have to parse the file manually then, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186357/importing-csv-file-with-multiple-character-separator-to-r).

Comment: You probably want to set both the quotes and sep option then. Do the individual lines begin/end with `"`s?

Answer (score 0):

`sep` can only be one character, but you can open your file `x` e.g. with [`readLines`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/readLines) and exchange your `","` separator e.g. with `\t` by using [`gsub`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/grep).

```
read.table(text=gsub("\",\"", "\t", readLines("x")))
```