# Reading a DAT file with vertical rectangle separators in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to import data from a DAT file but the text is separated by white rectangles, looks like "25af" characters but R doesn't recognise this as a separator.

Has anyone encountered this before? This file is encoded via ANSI if this helps?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related post? https://stackoverflow.com/q/18186357/680068

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
read.csv(text = gsub("\u25af", ",", readLines("my_file.dat", encoding = "UTF-8")))
```